# Moving %UserProfile% to new HDD via mklink

Tags: windows, hard-drive, symbolic-link

I'm trying to move my `%UserProfile%` from `F:` to a new HDD [`L:`] to give me more space, but I'm having some problems after I added `L:`, copied everything from `F:` to `L:`, and used Disk Management to relabel `F:` to `M:` and `L:` to `F:`

- When I reboot and login, it logs me into a temporary profile, without connecting to the user details on the new drive, even though I can see the files in the right path [disk and junction is okay]; I've tried deleting the old junction and recreating it with `mklink /d` [symbolic instead of junction] with the same result

I'm pretty sure when I originally set this up on `F:`, I copied the files, ran the below, and it all worked:

```
mklink /J F:\Users\<user> C:\Users\<user>
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: `%UserProfile%` is **not** meant to be moved to a different location due to the hard links contained within it _(e.g. `%UserProfile%\Application Data`, etc.)_ and doing so will result in user profile stability issues _(doing so corrupts the user profile by breaking hard links)_, coupled with previously breaking Windows bi-annual updates. There is no reason to move `%UserProfile%`, as you can move the data folders [`Documents`, `Downloads`, etc.] via the _Location_ tab in _Properties_, of which contains the bulk of the size, as well as `%AppData%`, `%Tmp%`, and `%Temp%`.

Comment: Thanks for the warning.  I've been running with my Users/username directory on F: drive for over 5 years now, on a computer that I use all day every day for code development.  I've never noticed any issues, and it seems to be running nicely now, having done it a second time.  I'm starting to think about a new PC, so maybe I'll do it the right way next time.  :)  I just had a look through, and I actually have quite a bit of stuff that's outside the standard moveable directories too (One drive, virtual machines, AppData is 38GB, and that doesn't seem to be moveable)

Comment: Whether or not you've experienced issues at the user level, you have broken hard links that are not fixable once broken, such as `%UserProfile%\Application Data`. Just an FYI, OneDrive can be moved anywhere _(to do so, sign out of the app, move the directory to another location, sign back in on the app, choose the customization option link (I can't recall its actual name), and choose the OneDrive folder that was just moved)_ and `%AppData%` can be moved, but `%LocalAppData%` cannot because it also contains hard links.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't copied `NTUSER.DAT`, and after using WinRE's command line to run `Xcopy /H`, copying `NTUSER.DAT` and a couple of other files, as well as swapping the drives over, it's all good now.

Comment: `%UserProfile%` is **not** meant to be moved to a different location due to the hard links contained within it _(e.g. `%UserProfile%\Application Data`, etc.)_ and doing so will result in user profile stability issues _(doing so corrupts the user profile by breaking hard links)_, coupled with previously breaking Windows bi-annual updates. There is no reason to move `%UserProfile%`, as you can move the data folders [`Documents`, `Downloads`, etc.] via the _Location_ tab in _Properties_, of which contains the bulk of the size, as well as `%AppData%`, `%Tmp%`, and `%Temp%`.

Comment: although you think you have moved the folder, if you check the original location the system will ignore the changes you made.